# Does localizing an existing Android app to several new locales constitute a new version?

Tags: android

I published an app to the market one month ago but in English only.
I called it Version 1.0 (after the recommendation).
I have since added four more locales to this exact same app (no other
changes!). So it is avail now in 5 languages:

1) English
2) French
3) Italian
4) Japanese
5) German

So, exact same app but localized for four new locales. How should I
release it? Version 1.1? Version 1.01?
Or leave it as 1.0 but call it an upgrade. I don't know and would
appreciate some guidance from more experienced developers.

Comment: Just to clarify, since I know the person who posted this question. He created a Trivia game called "something something Trivia 1.0", and he's not just talking about the versionName/versionCode in the Manifest file, but he's also wondering about the "1.0" in the app name as well.

Comment: Ah, well then, the solution would be to get the version number out of the app name and let `versionName` do the talking.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want. Just increment the version, 1.1 or 1.01, doesn't matter, and release it as an upgrade. In Eclipse, just increment the version code and the version name can be anything you want.

If you change anything then I'd call it a new version. Whether you want it to be 1.01 or 1.1 is up to you. Usually 1.01 indicates a small change while 1.1 would indicate a bigger change.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to increment the `versionCode` attribute in the manifest so the Market app on the handset will realize that the APK Google calls current is different than the one that's installed.  (The Market should complain if you try to upload an APK with the same version code, but I haven't tried it.)

The `versionName` is completely arbitrary.  You could, conceivably, leave it as it is, but I think it would leave people scratching their heads when someone says "Version 1.0 is localized for German" and someone else looks at their version 1.0 and finds that it isn't.

So my recommendation is call it a new version since it is materially different than the previous release.  I number mine *x.yy*, where *x* is the major version and *yy* is the minor version, but the choice is up to you.  I've been tempted just to call them "Version 1," "Version 2," "Version 3," etc.

Comment: Thanks all around for the feedback!!